# Centering Bootstrap columns when they are aligned vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a bit of trouble with bootstrap columns centering when it is collapsed to mobile view;

```html
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>Some Text</h1>
        <img src="#" width="250px" height="250px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>more text here</h2>
    </div>
```

I am using code similar to this and when I go into chrome inspect element and click the mobile button and collapse the view the first column will go on top of the second column but will not center in the middle of the page which is what I want. Do you have any ideas how I would fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap' offset classes so it requires no change in markup and no extra CSS. The key is to set an offset equal to half of the remaining size of the row. You are using even column widths, so this could work. Here is a link to Bootstrap offsets: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Specifically for mobile, you can change the column widths for different size devices. You are only specifying md in your example. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete. A combination of offsetting columns and device size will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2">
        <h1>Some Text</h1>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>more text here</h2>
    </div>
 
 
 </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/25v02f7g/2/)

Comment: This works sorta it does what i want but i only want it to be centered when on a mobile view and when on a computer they should be side by side

Comment: Updated the fiddle let me know if this works [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/25v02f7g/2/)